# Google drive realtime API getting ID of custom collaborative object

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I've written a simple application that uses a bunch of nested collaborative maps.  However, I've decided to convert this to using custom collaborative objects as it will clean up the structure of my model enormously.

How do I get the ID of a custom object?  Whenever I create a collaborative map or string (etc) they have an ID property.

Thanks,
Ryan.

Comment: Check the [`static getID`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.custom#.getId) if it can help you. It will return the id of the given custom object. For more information, check this [overview](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.custom) of custom and this [Custom collaborative objects](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/custom-objects).

Comment: Your comment @KENdi is the right answer and something I missed in the API documentationn - if you post it as the answer then I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`static getID`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.custom#.getId) if it can help you. It will return the id of the given custom object. For more information, check this [overview](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.custom) of custom and this [Custom collaborative objects](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/custom-objects).